# Changes to Python since Dive into Python

Tags: python

I've been teaching myself Python by working through [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) by Mark Pilgrim. I thoroughly recommend it, as do [other Stack Overflow users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570/what-is-the-best-quick-read-python-book-out-there/34608#34608).

However, the last update to Dive Into Python was five years ago. I look forward to reading the new [Dive into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.net/) When I make the switch to 3.x, but for now, using django means I'll stick to 2.x.

I'm interested to know what new features of Python I'm missing out on, if I've used Dive Into Python as my primary resource for learning the language. A couple of examples that I've come across are

- itertools
- ElementTree

Is there anything else I'm missing out on?

edit: As Bastien points out in his answer, I could just read the [What's New in Python](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/) pages, but sometimes it's fun to discover a useful tip on Stack Overflow rather than struggle through the complete, comprehensive answer in the official documentation.

Comment: Dict comprehensions -- but you have to wait for Python 3 for those.

Comment: SO at its worst -- three answers so far, and each is wrong (either mentions a feature that was already in the 2.2 Mark was writing about, or is talking about Python 3 when you so clearly said you're sticking to Python 2.* for now -- cheez).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [What's New in Python](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/). It has all the versions in the 2.x series. Per Alex's comments, you'll want to look at all Python 2.x for x > 2.

Highlights for day-to-day coding:

*Enumeration*: Instead of doing:

```
for i in xrange(len(sequence)):
    val = sequence[i]
    pass
```

You can now more succinctly write:

```
for i, val in enumerate(iterable):
    pass
```

This is important because it works for non-getitemable iterables (you would otherwise have to use an incrementing index counter alongside value iteration).

*Logging*: a sane alternative to print-based debugging, standardized in a Log4j-style library module.

*Booleans*: True and False, added for clarity: `return True` clearer intention than `return 1`.

*Generators*: An expressive form of lazy evaluation

```
evens = (i for i in xrange(limit) if i % 2 == 0)
```

*Extended slices*: Builtins support strides in slices.

```
assert [1, 2, 3, 4][::2] == [1, 3]
```

*Sets*: For O(1) lookup semantics, you no longer have to do:

```
pseudo_set = {'foo': None, 'bar': None}
assert 'foo' in pseudo_set
```

You can now do:

```
set_ = set(['foo', 'bar'])
assert 'foo' in set_
```

*Reverse iteration*: `reversed(sequence)` is more readable than `sequence[::-1]`.

*Subprocess*: Unifies all the ways you might want to invoke a subprocess -- capturing outputs, feeding input, blocking or non-blocking.

*Conditional expressions*: There's an issue with the idiom:

```
a and b or c
```

Namely, when b is falsy. `b if a else c` resolves that issue.

*Context management*: Resource acquisition/release simplified via the `with` statement.

```
with open(filename) as file:
    print file.read()
# File is closed outside the `with` block.
```

*Better string formatting*: Too much to describe -- see Python documentation under `str.format()`.

Comment: I should also note generators are more than an expressive form of lazy evaluation nowadays -- they support full coroutine behaviors. It's simpler to describe them the former way. :-)

Comment: Oh, and simple generators let you write simple state machines very easily in day-to-day work, via `yield`. This is handy for things like custom iterators.

Answer (score 6):

Mark(author of the book) had [some comments](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8miar/im_new_to_python_should_i_read_dive_into_python_3/c09s45y) on this. I've shamelessly copied the related paragraph here:
"""If you choose Python 2, I can only recommend "Dive Into Python" chapters 2-7, 13-15, and 17. The rest of the book is horribly out of date."""

Comment: That's good advice. I might have skipped through the XML and SOAP chapters quicker if I'd read that before.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of examples of the sort of answer I was thinking of:

#### Conditional Expressions

Instead of the [and-or trick](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html#d0e9975), 2.5 offers a new way to write [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html?highlight=with_statement#pep-308-conditional-expressions).

```
#and-or trick:
x = condition and 'true_value' or 'false_value'

#new in 2.5:
x = 'true_value' if condition else 'false_value'
```

#### Testing for keys in dictionaries

has_key() [is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=has_key#dict.has_key) in favor of key in d.

```
>>>d={'key':'value','key2':'value2'}
>>>'key1' in d
 True
```

Comment: This should probably be part of the question as examples of the type of answers that you're looking for. (But I'm slightly bitter because it has more up-votes than my answer. ;-)

Comment: @cdleary I don't think there's anything wrong with answering your own question on SO. My answer really is an answer, because I discovered both examples in the What's New in Python documents after asking the question.

I liked your answer, and up-voted it. I'm pleased that I'm familiar with most of the things you mention - it shows that learning with Dive Into Python hasn't left me writing archaic 2.2 code.

Answer (score 2):

A few "minor" features were added in 2.4 and are pervasive in new 2.x python code: decorator (2.4) and try/except/finally clauses. Before you could not do:

```
try:
    do_something()
except FunkyException:
    handle_exception():
finally:
    clean_up()
```

Both are essentially syntactic sugar, though, since you could do the same, just with a bit more code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import antigravity
```

[See the documentation](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/python.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read the “what's in Python 2.x?” documents.
Some things that may have missed:

- New-style classes (allows standard types subtyping, properties, ...).
- The `with` keyword, which helps allocating and releasing resources.

Comment: New classes were already in 2.2 (which Mark was writing about).